# Loading a XML file as a resource

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

I am making a game that uses xml files to store data. I am trying to build a class that will load a template xml file to hold a variety of data. I would like to use this template file as a JAR resource, however I am running into a problem where it will say the file is empty (`java.lang.NullPointerException`)

My question is, how do I set up the files to be used as resources correctly?

The code:

```
public XMLFileReader(String Item_Name) {

    URL test = this.getClass().getResource("Reasource/Example.txt");

    System.out.print(test.getPath());

    try {
        URL is = this.getClass().getResource("Reasources/" + Item_Name);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is.getFile());

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new XMLFileReader("Example.xml");
}
```

The file structure:

```
 Main Project
 |
 |-Reasources
 |      |
 |      |-Example.txt
 |
 |-XMlTest
     |
     |-XmlFileReader
```

The Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Utils.File_Utils.XMLFileReader.<init>(XMLFileReader.java:32)
at Utils.File_Utils.XMLFileReader.main(XMLFileReader.java:68)
```

Comment: First, your hard coded URL has a different path than your one based on Item_Name ("Reasource" vs "Reasources"). That may just be a typo in the code, however. If it is, showing us the stack trace of the error would be helpful, so we know what is throwing the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `Resources\Example.txt` file is in `classpath.`

if you are running from cmd line then,

```
java -cp Resources\Example.txt YourClassFile
```

and also you are using absolute classpath, instead use relative path like `/Resources or ./Resources`.